# Lightning Components in Communities

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community

We are trying to put a canvas app in a lightning component and it is returning a blank page.
We have a visualforce page which has a canvas app and it is working fine but putting the same canvas app in the component makes it fail.

Component code is :

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="GLOBAL">
<force:canvasApp applicationName="Dashboards" onCanvasAppError="{!c.canvasAppError}" width="100%"
                                parameters='{
                                            "ts.name":"folder/filename", 
                                            "ts.tabs":"no",
                                            "ts.toolbar":"no",
                                            "ts.trustedTicket.username":"salesforce_user",
                                            }'/> 
</aura:component>
```

---

```
<apex:canvasApp applicationName="Dashboards" width="100%"
                                parameters="
                                            {
                                            'ts.name':'folder/file.name', 
                                            'ts.tabs':'no',
                                            'ts.toolbar':'no',
                                           'ts.trustedTicket.username':sf_user',}/>
```

Comment: There will be more support for Canvas in Lightning Components in W18. Check the W18 Release notes to see if it applies to your particular situation.

Comment: If you need help debugging - try adding your component to an app so that exceptions wouldn't be suppressed. Also, you can enable "Pause on exceptions" feature in Chrome debugger.

Comment: May just be a copy / paste error, but it looks like the parameters attribute is invalid in the second example? There's no open single quote mark for `sf.user`, and no closing double quote for the attribute as a whole.